# Bootstrap 3 Css text inside a div with specified height

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the following problem.

I have a div with a specified Height  of 100px. inside this div i want to place a text.
and later i want to to test with javascript of the text is bigger so i can adjust it's size to make it fit.

but the problem is that because of the height contrain the text just gets cut off so i can't test if the width of the text is bigger than the containing div.

how to fix so that the text breaks out of the div?

Here is a JSBIN with the problem.

http://jsbin.com/UFoRIYex/574/edit

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does `display:table` and `white-space:nowrap;` will help ? http://jsbin.com/UFoRIYex/576/edit

Comment: yeah it works, but the the attributes at to be assigned to the h1 so i can check the length in comparison to the div. Thank you!